# Error while Adding Element to XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml

I am implementing a JAXB program in Java to generate XML file.

Now, I have following XML structure to be built:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<DataPDU xmlns="urn:cma:stp:xsd:stp.1.0">
    <Body>
        <CreditDetails xmlns="asdasd">
         .
         .
        </CreditDetails>
    <Body>
</DataPDU>
```

I have written the following code for making the above format:

**main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        
        Document doc = new Document();

        CreditTransactionDetails creditDetail1 = new CreditTransactionDetails();
        creditDetail1.setAccountNo(123456);
        doc.getBody().getCreditDetails().add(creditDetail1);
        CreditTransactionDetails creditDetail2 = new CreditTransactionDetails();
        creditDetail2.setAccountNo(123123);
        doc.getBody().getCreditDetails().add(creditDetail2);
        // could make your classes a bit more pretty, e.g. Factory methods or constructor

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(doc, writer);
        System.out.println(writer.toString()); // gives your XML

    }
```

**Document**

```
package com.cdc.mappers;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "DataPDU")
public class Document {
    
    private Body body;
    

    public void setBody(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Body")
    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }
    
}
```

**Body**

```
package com.cdc.mappers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Body {

    @XmlElement(name = "creditDetails")
    private List<CreditTransactionDetails> creditDetails = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<CreditTransactionDetails> getCreditDetails() {
        return creditDetails;
    }
}
```

**CreditDetails**

```
package com.cdc.mappers;

public class CreditTransactionDetails {

    private int accountNo;
      public int getAccountNo() {
        return accountNo;
      }
      public void setAccountNo(int accountNo) {
        this.accountNo = accountNo;
      }
}
```

When I execute code, its giving null pointer on following line of main class:

**doc.getBody().getCreditDetails().add(creditDetail1);**

I am new to JAXB.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: From the first look at the xml-snippet it looks like <Body> is missing a closing tag. Could that cause it?

Comment: Thats the sample of the XML i want. There is something to fix in the Java Code to generate that XML

Comment: In your document class, there is no Body object created. Could it be that you are trying to access a non-existing body? Because I can't find an instance of the body being created or set.

Comment: Thanks a lot --> updating the line to **private Body body = new Body();** solved the issue :)

Comment: That is up to you. You can create that in the constructor of the document or create it in your main and set it via `doc.setBody(bodyObj)`.

Comment: Glad it worked. :)